# Fading in an object when hovering over another one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to slide down a tooltip element when hovering on another element.

I tried using jQuery, but i'm experiencing that nothing will be faded in if I `hover` on `countbox1`. `countbox1` is a timer made with javascript.

I don't think the script is wrong. I think it doesn't detect jQuery for some reason.

I also tried to download jQuery and put this in the "src:" directly.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#countbox1").onmouseover(function(){
    $("#tooltip").fadeIn();
  });
  $("#countbox1").onmouseout(function(){
    $("#tooltip").fadeOut();
  });
});
```

```css
#countbox1 {
  width: 400px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: bebas;
  font-size: 70px;
  color: white;
  cursor: default;
}

#tooltip {
  width: 500px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  color: white;
  font-family: mix_thin;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="home">
  <p id="tooltip">Wochen:Tage:Stunden:Minuten:Sekunden</p>
  <div id="countbox1"></div>
  <hr style="width: 500px;">
</div>
```

Comment: it is `mouseover` not `onmouseover` same way `mouseout` not `onmouseout`

Comment: @Arun is right, but if you don't have specific needing, I would suggest to use CSS animations instead, I'll make a little fiddle for you

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pcuc9aph/1/

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is the tooltip to enter the screen on hover of something else, I'd suggest using CSS `transition`.

If you nest the `<p id="tooltip">` within the `#countbox1` and put a `:hover`-event on that, you can get exactly the thing you want.

**HTML**

```
<div id=home>
    <div id="countbox1">
        <p id="tooltip">Wochen:Tage:Stunden:Minuten:Sekunden</p>
    </div>
    <hr style="width: 500px;">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#home {
    height: 50%;
    background: red;
}

#countbox1 {
    width: 400px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: bebas;
    font-size: 70px;
    color: white;
    cursor: default;
    height: 50px;
    background: #f4f4f4;
}

#countbox1:hover #tooltip {
    opacity: 1;

}

#tooltip {
    width: 500px;
    color: white;
    font-family: mix_thin;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 30px;
    background: #0000ff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    top: -15px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 1s;
}
```

[Here's a working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b548cm4s/1/). Hover over the grey area for the tooltip to enter the view.

[Here's a working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b548cm4s/) where the tooltip enters the screen from the top.

Comment: Which I mention in the beginning with `if you nest the...`

Answer (score 0):

You might be using deprecated methods.

Replace your code for the one below, and try again:

```
$(document).on('ready',function(){
    $("#countbox1").on('mouseover',function(){
        $("#tooltip").stop(true).fadeIn();
    });
    $("#countbox1").on('mouseout',function(){
        $("#tooltip").stop(true).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use `mouseover` instead of `onmouseover`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#home").mouseover(function(){
    $("#tooltip").fadeIn();
  });
  $("#home").mouseout(function(){
    $("#tooltip").fadeOut();
  });
});
```

```css
#countbox1 {
  width: 400px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: bebas;
  font-size: 70px;
  color: white;
  cursor: default;
}

#tooltip {
  width: 500px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  color: white;
  font-family: mix_thin;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id=home>
    <p id="tooltip">Wochen:Tage:Stunden:Minuten:Sekunden</p><div id="countbox1"></div>
    <hr style="width: 500px;">
  </div>
</body>
```

Check it out also on this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cjeLzf79/).